# Jest and Enzyme, Invariant Violation even when already wrapping a Router on the test

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-dom

I'm trying to test a component that uses `Link`. This said component is loaded by a parent that uses `BrowserRouter`.

I'm getting the below error while running the test:

```
  Invariant Violation: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

      16 |   const getPlanDetail = () => Promise.resolve(PlanDetail);
      17 |
    > 18 |   const wrapper = mount(
         |                   ^
      19 |     <StaticRouter location="/viewDetail/1" context={{}}>
      20 |       <PlanDetail getPlanDetail={getPlanDetail} />
      21 |     </StaticRouter>
```

And I'm at loss on what to do. Previously, just adding the wrapper `StaticRouter` worked perfectly, now I'm unsure on what's missing.

My import on the test file is
`import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';`

Also tried wrapping the component with `MemoryRouter` instead of `StaticRouter`, same result.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was missing this step:

> Don’t forget to mock the BrowserRouter used by App.js by creating
>   **mocks**/react-router-dom.js and here is how to mock it:

```
import React from 'react';
const rrd = require('react-router-dom');
// Just render plain div with its children
rrd.BrowserRouter = ({children}) => <div>{children}</div>
module.exports = rrd;
```

Credit to this [blog post](https://medium.com/@antonybudianto/react-router-testing-with-jest-and-enzyme-17294fefd303).